# How would I run Maven code is not working with pom.xml file

Tags: maven, selenium, pom.xml

This above code is showing error. I think mark-up error probably. what would the solution.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPiwG.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please add the pom as text instead of image here?

Comment: It seems that you forgot to add the group id and artifact id of maven compiler plugin in the pom.xml. I've added more details in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

In the pom file, you have not added group id and artifact id before adding configuration tags in the first plugin. Also, I see that you have given group id and artifact id of the project at line number 4 and 5 as that of maven compiler plugin. Are line numbers 4, 5, and 6 a result of copy-paste typo? I assume what you meant was this:

```xml
<build>
  <plugins>
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire</artifactId>
        <!-- add required version number here if applicable -->
      </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
```

You need to edit the group id and artifact id in line number 4 and line number 5 to match with what you have as the package name.
Line numbers 4,5 and 6 should be something similar to this instead:

```xml
<groupId>com.vogella.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>quickstart</artifactId>
<name>quickstart</name>
```

Once you add those details, your pom.xml should become parsable and the error should go away.

Answer (score 0):

**Things that can be checked in pom.xml:**

**1.** Check if the correct repository is specified in the pom.xml from which the package was downloaded originally. It might happen that the url in pom.xml is not correct and you have the required jar file in the .m2 repository.

**2.** Check for the artifact version, if the version specified in the pom.xml is there in the repository from where it should be downloaded.

**3.** Check if the jar is missing or not. If yes, place it manually in the .m2 repository. Sometimes the jar mentioned in the pom.xml is not downloaded and it gives error.

**4.** You can also try deleting the entire .m2 repository folder and run the maven build. The jars get downloaded from scratch. It might resolve the problem as well.

**5.** In eclipse, you can always try to clean the project by selecting the Project->Clean option. There are a few other options apart from Project->Clean, some of which are more along the lines of turning it off and on again.
 **1.** Try right-clicking on the project and select Maven->Update Project.
 **2.** Disable then re-enable dependency management (right-click Maven->Disable Maven 
      Nature then to again convert the project to a Maven project, Right Click on the 
      project and select Configure ->Convert To Maven Project. Please refer to the screen 
      shots below.
  **3.** Close the project and reopen it.